# How to add 2 more members in highchart map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

Below is the highchart map link,

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/data-class-two-ranges/

Currently, it shows only 2 peoples(Obama and Romney).
How to add more 2 peoples in it.

The reference spreedsheet that above uses is,

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0AoIaUO7wH1HwdDFXSlpjN2J4aGg5MkVHWVhsYmtyVWc/od6/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=jQuery1113010653590187448114_1442138646453&_=1442138646454
```

I will be deeply thankful for any help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updated fiddle with adding new people 
 I changed colorAxis as below , instead of -100 to 0 and  0 to 100 , I changed from -100 to 0 then 0 to 10 and then upto 100

```
                colorAxis: {

                    dataClasses: [{
                        from: -100,
                        to: 0,
                        color: '#C40401',
                        name: 'Romney'
                    }, {
                        from: 0,
                        to: 10,
                        color: '#0200D0',
                        name: 'Obama'
                    }, {
                        from: 10,
                        to: 100,
                        color: '#ff9634',
                        name: 'Nishith'
                    }]
                },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/kye3ksy8/

Comment: Thanks Nishith. How can i make it to read spreadsheet from local system where the code will be hosted?

Comment: It would be a cross origin request ,jsonP   could be used. But in your code environment what technologies you are using to fetch data from server ?

Comment: Hi Nishith. I want to use PHP in server side and frontend HTML, Javascript, Jquery. But i only need help in frontend. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your PHP returns JSON or something different? Read the article about [working with data](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-intro) or check similar topics on SO.

Comment: Paste your json here or on fiddle